# how to fetch checkbox value in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox

I am creating mvc4 applicationn using entity framework 5
i am creating a page this contains checkboxes
i created table in db

model class

```
public class EmpSkillSet
    {

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Skill { get; set; }
        public bool isSelected { get; set; }
    }
}
```

controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public string AddSkills(IEnumerable<EmpSkillSet> skills)
        {  

          }
```

How do I create a checkbox in the view?
Then how do i get its value from the database?

Comment: How do you fetch any other value from the db?

Comment: i create the object of edmx designer file. but how to create check box from db is my problem

Answer (score 0):

By using this example you can fetch only boolen value (True or False)

In view:

```
@Html.CheckBox("MonOpen", l.MonOpen)
```

In MOdel:

```
public class Shop
{
public bool MonOpen { get; set; }
....
}
```

in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ShopCreate(Shop location)
{
  Location newShop = new Location();
  newShop.MonOpen = location.MonOpen;
  ....
}
```